# Change a Property's type using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, properties

Let's suppose I have the following class:

```
public class UniqueEntity {
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to be able to change the type of `Key`, from `System.Object` to `System.Int32`, at runtime.

I would guess the only way this can be accomplished (if it can) is using **reflection**.

The property's type can be obtained via the `PropertyType`'s property of `PropertyInfo` (sorry for the redundance).

```
typeof(UniqueEntity).GetProperty("Key").PropertyType;
```

The problem is that it is read-only. I can't set the value as `PropertyType = typeof(int);`.

Is there a possible way to change a property's type?

Comment: For the record. I want to do this because `Key` will be annotated with an attribute. An external Framework will identify that property and get its type from `PropertyType`. It'd be great if `System.Int32` is returned instead of `System.Object`

Comment: Interesting question. I don't believe you can do this at runtime. But being an object you can store anything in it and then just do runtime casting.

Comment: Not possible that you want, But you can inherit this class and create new property that cast that property and you use only the new property.

Comment: What would you achieve by doing this? Any code making use of the property will assume that the type is `Object` and will not have, for example, calls on the proper to methods that only work on `Int32` or arithmetic operators. This looks like a classic case of an XY Problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so...

The main issue was that I had this class:

```
public class UniqueEntity {
    [key]
    public object Key { get; set; }
}
```

But `EntityFramework` messes up table creation when handling `object` keys. My idea was that the key could be any type, specified by the child class.

I started using generics:

```
public class UniqueEntity<T> where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>
{
     [Key]
     public T Key { get; set; }
}
```

This worked well at the beginning, but led to serious design problems later on when creating my generic repositories (Repository definition would be like `IRepository<T,E>`, when `IRepository<E>` would be enough.

---

So, `EntityFramework` uses the `PropertyInfo` value of the property annotated with the `Key` attribute, to get the entity's key type. If only I could change that type to whatever the user wanted it to be (at runtime), and avoid using generics at all, it'd be great.

---

It turns out you cannot delete a property, or change its type buuuuuut.. You can actually create a new dummy property with custom attributes, and remove the attribute from the original `Key` property!!

For that, we need a `CustomReflectionContext` (System.Reflection.Context):

```
public class Modifier : CustomReflectionContext
{
    private string propName;
    private object propValue;

    public Modifier(string propName, object propValue)
    {
        this.propName = propName;
        this.propValue = propValue;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> AddProperties(Type type)
    {
        Type newType = MapType(propValue.GetType().GetTypeInfo());
        return CreateProperty(newType, propName, o => propValue, (o, v) => propValue = v,
                                    new Attribute[] { new KeyAttribute() }, new Attribute[] { }, new Attribute[] { });
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetCustomAttributes(MemberInfo member, IEnumerable<object> declaredAttributes)
    {
        return new Attribute[] { };
    }
}
```

With the help of this little class, we are able to create our own custom type to give to `EntityFramework`, and with a new property that has now the `[Key]` annotation:

```
    var context = new Modifier("NewKey", 0);
    var uniqueEntityType = context.MapType(typeof(UniqueEntity).GetTypeInfo());
    var keyType = uniqueEntityType.GetProperty("Key").PropertyType;
    var keyAttrs = uniqueEntityType.GetProperty("Key").GetCustomAttributes();
    var newKeyType = uniqueEntityType.GetProperty("NewKey").PropertyType;
    var newKeyAttrs = uniqueEntityType.GetProperty("NewKey").GetCustomAttributes();
    Console.WriteLine("Key Property. Type: {0}, Attribute: {1}", keyType, keyAttrs.FirstOrDefault());
    Console.WriteLine("NewKey Property. Type: {0}, Attribute: {1}", newKeyType, newKeyAttrs.FirstOrDefault());
    Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: Proof Image]

Answer (score 0):

No. The type of any class member, whether field, property, or method return value, as well as the types of any method parameters, is determined at compile time.

In your example, you could store an `Int32` in the property. It would be "boxed", and you could cast it back to `Int32` as needed. But the type of the *property* itself would remain `Object`.

Comment: The problem is that an external framework uses the value in `PropertyType` to do its work. It messes up if its `System.Object`.

Comment: @MatiCicero: can you not make different classes that have different types for this property? Can you use attributes to adjust the framework's behavior? Are there hooks in the framework that let you do custom processing?

Comment: @MatiCicero: sorry. The specific problem doesn't change the rules of the language. It sounds like you will have to create a "shim" object that can act as a proxy between your external framework and your internal entity type.